# How to get around "Instance attribute defined outside __init__" warning from PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have written this class with a load of variables in it that I need to be able to reset to defaults at any point. Initially I "declared" and initialised (as much as you seem to be able to declare in Python) these in `__init__` but that gave the problem that when I wanted an external force to set these variables to the default value I'd have to repeat thirty odd lines of code (as the class has about thirty variables).

I have seen one other post here that describes a similar issue, but the accepted answer was to set each variable to None and then you can access them from functions within the class without an issue.

In C++ you'd declare these variables as variables in the header and then you could call the same function both at instantiation and when `class_name.set_to_default()` was called and that's all easy and neat.

Surely there is a way to do the same in Python without an error for each variable? Something like:

```
 class Motor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset_all_values()
  
    def reset_all_values(self):
        self.speed_value = DEFAULT_SPEED_VALUE
        self.hours_value = DEFAULT_HOURS_VALUE
        # etc.
```

If so, how can I do it without PyCharm whinging at me?

Or do I just have to be incredibly verbose in the code? Is Python too different from other languages and you have to think in a completely different way?

I think it's important to note that I am a C programmer, who also does a little C++ and I do realise it's possible I simply think too much in terms of those languages.